# Como instalar y visualizar correctamente un archivo pdf con mpdf en laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, mpdf

Actualmente tengo en vista un boton que me lleva hacia una ruta y lo que pretendo es hacer una prueba de visualizacion para un pdf de esta manera mostrare mi codigo. utilizo laravel 5.5

```
<a href="{{route('pdf')}}"  class="btn btn-info ">Detalle</a>
```

Controlador

```
public function dada(){

return view('Unidad_medida.pdf');

}
```

mi ruta

```
Route::get('Unidad_medida/pdf','UnidadmedidaController@dada')->name('pdf');
```

muestro el codigo de mi vista pdf

```
<?php

$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([]);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
$mpdf->Output();
```

ahora muestro la instalacion desde mi terminal, utilizo vscode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy teniendo este Problema al visualizar 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero es saber como instalar y visualizar correctamente esta libreria en laravel 5.5, y si tengo algo malo en mi codigo se lo agradeceria mucho.....